# flash (actionscript3) Socket connect to php page with $_GET param

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript, get

Hello i am trying to make a simple game but i need server, so i started learning for sockets on flash but when i send session to the php page with get parameter its like the page don't have get parameters and like i am just entering just the normal page (Example: index.php?something=something2 and it connects to index.php without the something)

Here is what i mean:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

The portocol i send:

```
mysocket.writeUTF(" GET /index.php?act=getip HTTP/1.1\r\n Host: 192.168.1.100\r\n\r\n");
```

My php page:

```
<?
include 'all.php';//mysql connect, escaping all get/post params
if($_GET["act"] == 'getip'){
die($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);//this must be printed on the screen
}
print 'asd';//<-------------------- i get this on connecting
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an HTTP based communication, just use `flash.net.URLLoader`.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://192.168.1.100/index.php?act=ip");

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var ip:String = loader.data;
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: What do you mean the page source code ? If you want to retrieve the response of the server, user `loader.data`.